# Clearing content of an excel cell based on name

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I would like to make a macro where I can delete the content of multiple cells based on names. For example I have a sheet where I have sheet1name1 and sheet2name2 and on another sheet I have where I used names sheet2name1 and sheet2name2. Is it possible to write a macro what will delete the content of these cells if the cells are named "sheet*name*"? The stars should point to numbers.

```
Sub RemNamedRanges() 
    Dim nm              As Name 
    On Error Resume Next 
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names 
        nm.Delete 
    Next 
    On Error Goto 0 
End Sub
```

This is to delete all, but I need only for some particular as I mentioned before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InStr` should be able to determine whether there is a substring within a string.

```
For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names 
    if cbool(instr(1, nm.name, "name", vbtextcompare)) then _
        nm.Delete 
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the right direction.  Change the `If` statement to match what you need (not sure if you're looking for `Sheet1`, or the sheet name in the workbook.)  Are you looping through your workbook?

```
Sub RemNamedRanges()
Dim nm      As Name
On Error Resume Next
For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If nm.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then
        Range(nm).ClearContents
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Should that be `Range(nm.name).ClearContents`?

Comment: @Jeeped - It works for me as-is, but works just as well with `Range(nm.Name)...`.

Comment: Oh-key-doh-key then. I thought you might have missed converting the name object to a string.